# Quitted last job because general delay in payment and the debt increased over time; it's been a year and situation hasn't changed, what should I do?

Tags: salary, resignation, legal, mexico

I worked for two years and a half in a not so well-payed job, which was my first formal one. They helped me a lot to grow as an employee, so the payment wasn't that much of a deal; besides, they also paid for a diplomat which got me my academic degree.

On my last year, the company went through a rough finance situation, they said that an expected huge (foreign; even) investment couldn't took place because of "trust contract issues" and some contracts couldn't be paid because political ones, since some of the clients were public ones. This led to an overall delay in payment, release of employees and even the disappearance of a complete business unit.

I lasted four more months like this, out of the kindness that they showed me, and quit because I couldn't manage anymore. They owed me about three months of work and some legal obligations. When I quit we signed an agreement with  the dates of debt payment, which never happened. After six months I talked again with them, asked for another agreement (a recommendation from a lawyer friend), the VP told me that they already had some contracts and payment orders, and such. The other agreement was due yesterday and nothing happened.

I haven't gone legal as I'm afraid I would spend time and money on something that wouldn't pay as much (it's not that much money, but I wouldn't want to renounce to i). I've played the polite approach, but it's certainly not working. What can I do to get paid?

Comment: Go the legal way

Comment: Where are you located? This is super important.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I've been told processes like this could last for years, and don't know much about the costs of this.

Comment: @Stephan I'm from Mexico.

Comment: In USA the tax authorities are first in line to get money from a failing company, and employees with unpaid wages are second in line. Labor ministries take a dim view of this kind of monkey business.  Get help.

Comment: And in the future, *never* continue working for a company once they start missing payroll obligations. I understand that you were grateful that they helped you get your diploma, but they got the benefit of your labour. And sadly, I think they took advantage of you. Even if they couldn't afford to pay all their employees at the end, they could have at least paid the junior employees. I assume your salary was very small compared to some of the highest paid employees.

Comment: Maybe your lawyer friend will handle it for you at "mates rates" ?

Comment: Often, just a letter from a lawyer usually focuses minds wonderfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complain to the Ministry of Labor in Mexico.

In most countries, the Ministry of Labor/Department of Labor/Labor Commissioner is in charge of recovering unpaid wages.

Unfortunately, I don't know Spanish, so I can't get the exact link for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your lawyer friend to do what he can, and quickly.

When a company is struggling, they'll have a big pile of debts like yours, and if they go bankrupt, almost none of those debts will be paid. The trick is to get at least part of what they owe you while there's still a chance.

The longer they continue like this, the more people will be hurt at the end.